# iperf3: unable to connect to server: Connection timed out

Tags: iperf3

It is necessary to check the connection speed, but it does not work. Virtual machines ping each other, but when iperf3 is started and I get an error for some waiting time
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.x.x` is an IP of a private network, while `172.24.x.x` is global.  Did you verify that the ping from the global IP to the private IP really reached the desired machine and not a machine on another private network with the same IP?

Suggest to try switching between the client and the server, i.e. the server will have the global IP, and see whether it works.

Another reason for such issue may be a firewall that can block TCP while not blocking ping.